# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find any build directories

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, apache-spark, apache-spark-standalone

I want to run spark master and worker in Intellij. I have started the spark master and worker successfully. The worker is also connected to master without any problem. I can confirm this by looking at logs and spark web UI. But the problem starts when I try to run any application on this setup. 
currently, I am trying to run the spark-shell on this setup, but when it try to master, I am getting some error messages on master and the IlligalStateException on the worker.

**Master Logs (started successfully)**

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/09/21 16:42:33 INFO Master: Started daemon with process name: 22237@rana-pc
16/09/21 16:42:33 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for TERM
16/09/21 16:42:33 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for HUP
16/09/21 16:42:33 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for INT
16/09/21 16:42:34 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/09/21 16:42:34 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: rana
16/09/21 16:42:34 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: rana
16/09/21 16:42:34 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
16/09/21 16:42:34 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
16/09/21 16:42:34 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(rana); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(rana); groups with modify permissions: Set()
16/09/21 16:42:35 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkMaster' on port 7077.
16/09/21 16:42:35 INFO Master: Starting Spark master at spark://MASTER_IP:7077
16/09/21 16:42:35 INFO Master: Running Spark version 2.0.0
16/09/21 16:42:35 INFO log: Logging initialized @3645ms
16/09/21 16:42:36 INFO Server: jetty-9.2.16.v20160414
16/09/21 16:42:36 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@12fb5c3b{/app,null,AVAILABLE}
16/09/21 16:42:36 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@48b5405c{/app/json,null,AVAILABLE}
16/09/21 16:42:36 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6bf42129{/,null,AVAILABLE}
16/09/21 16:42:36 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@17c4d9fc{/json,null,AVAILABLE}
16/09/21 16:42:36 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5f1655bb{/static,null,AVAILABLE}
16/09/21 16:42:36 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3dc349a5{/app/kill,null,AVAILABLE}
16/09/21 16:42:36 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@7774da5d{/driver/kill,null,AVAILABLE}
16/09/21 16:42:36 INFO ServerConnector: Started ServerConnector@678fff3{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
16/09/21 16:42:36 INFO Server: Started @3999ms
16/09/21 16:42:36 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'MasterUI' on port 8080.
16/09/21 16:42:36 INFO MasterWebUI: Bound MasterWebUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://MASTER_IP:8080
16/09/21 16:42:36 INFO Server: jetty-9.2.16.v20160414
16/09/21 16:42:36 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@49c1de92{/,null,AVAILABLE}
16/09/21 16:42:36 INFO ServerConnector: Started ServerConnector@3e8a8bfb{HTTP/1.1}{MASTER_IP:6066}
16/09/21 16:42:36 INFO Server: Started @4050ms
16/09/21 16:42:36 INFO Utils: Successfully started service on port 6066.
16/09/21 16:42:36 INFO StandaloneRestServer: Started REST server for submitting applications on port 6066
16/09/21 16:42:36 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@185eae98{/metrics/master/json,null,AVAILABLE}
16/09/21 16:42:36 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6f634fcf{/metrics/applications/json,null,AVAILABLE}
16/09/21 16:42:36 INFO Master: I have been elected leader! New state: ALIVE
16/09/21 16:42:46 INFO Master: Registering worker MASTER_IP:42839 with 6 cores, 6.7 GB RAM
```

**Worker Log (Started Successfully)**

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/09/21 17:24:08 INFO Worker: Started daemon with process name: 24007@rana-pc
16/09/21 17:24:08 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for TERM
16/09/21 17:24:08 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for HUP
16/09/21 17:24:08 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for INT
16/09/21 17:24:08 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/09/21 17:24:08 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: rana
16/09/21 17:24:08 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: rana
16/09/21 17:24:08 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
16/09/21 17:24:08 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
16/09/21 17:24:08 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(rana); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(rana); groups with modify permissions: Set()
16/09/21 17:24:09 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkWorker' on port 50059.
16/09/21 17:24:09 INFO Worker: Starting Spark worker MASTER_IP:50059 with 6 cores, 6.7 GB RAM
16/09/21 17:24:09 INFO Worker: Running Spark version 2.0.0
16/09/21 17:24:09 INFO Worker: Spark home: /usr/local/spark
16/09/21 17:24:09 INFO log: Logging initialized @2328ms
16/09/21 17:24:09 INFO Server: jetty-9.2.16.v20160414
16/09/21 17:24:09 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@251c286b{/logPage,null,AVAILABLE}
16/09/21 17:24:09 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@c5c7b5f{/logPage/json,null,AVAILABLE}
16/09/21 17:24:09 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4aa264e6{/,null,AVAILABLE}
16/09/21 17:24:09 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1f240248{/json,null,AVAILABLE}
16/09/21 17:24:09 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5b3f3eb7{/static,null,AVAILABLE}
16/09/21 17:24:09 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@34d6200c{/log,null,AVAILABLE}
16/09/21 17:24:09 INFO ServerConnector: Started ServerConnector@4eaf8f4d{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8081}
16/09/21 17:24:09 INFO Server: Started @2440ms
16/09/21 17:24:09 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'WorkerUI' on port 8081.
16/09/21 17:24:09 INFO WorkerWebUI: Bound WorkerWebUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://MASTER_IP:8081
16/09/21 17:24:09 INFO Worker: Connecting to master MASTER_IP:7077...
16/09/21 17:24:09 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@270d60ee{/metrics/json,null,AVAILABLE}
16/09/21 17:24:09 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to /MASTER_IP:7077 after 35 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
16/09/21 17:24:10 INFO Worker: Successfully registered with master spark://MASTER_IP:7077
```

**Master Logs (when try to run spark-shell)**

```
16/09/21 17:26:08 INFO Master: Registering app Spark shell
16/09/21 17:26:08 INFO Master: Registered app Spark shell with ID app-20160921172608-0000
16/09/21 17:26:08 INFO Master: Launching executor app-20160921172608-0000/0 on worker worker-20160921172409-MASTER_IP-50059
16/09/21 17:26:09 INFO Master: Removing executor app-20160921172608-0000/0 because it is FAILED
16/09/21 17:26:09 INFO Master: Launching executor app-20160921172608-0000/1 on worker worker-20160921172409-MASTER_IP-50059
16/09/21 17:26:09 INFO Master: Removing executor app-20160921172608-0000/1 because it is FAILED
16/09/21 17:26:09 INFO Master: Launching executor app-20160921172608-0000/2 on worker worker-20160921172409-MASTER_IP-50059
16/09/21 17:26:09 INFO Master: Removing executor app-20160921172608-0000/2 because it is FAILED
16/09/21 17:26:09 INFO Master: Launching executor app-20160921172608-0000/3 on worker worker-20160921172409-MASTER_IP-50059
16/09/21 17:26:09 INFO Master: Removing executor app-20160921172608-0000/3 because it is FAILED
16/09/21 17:26:09 INFO Master: Launching executor app-20160921172608-0000/4 on worker worker-20160921172409-MASTER_IP-50059
16/09/21 17:26:09 INFO Master: Removing executor app-20160921172608-0000/4 because it is FAILED
16/09/21 17:26:09 INFO Master: Launching executor app-20160921172608-0000/5 on worker worker-20160921172409-MASTER_IP-50059
16/09/21 17:26:09 INFO Master: Removing executor app-20160921172608-0000/5 because it is FAILED
16/09/21 17:26:09 INFO Master: Launching executor app-20160921172608-0000/6 on worker worker-20160921172409-MASTER_IP-50059
16/09/21 17:26:09 INFO Master: Removing executor app-20160921172608-0000/6 because it is FAILED
```

**Worker Logs(when try to run spark-shell)**

```
16/09/21 17:26:09 INFO Worker: Asked to launch executor app-20160921172608-0000/0 for Spark shell
16/09/21 17:26:09 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: rana
16/09/21 17:26:09 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: rana
16/09/21 17:26:09 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
16/09/21 17:26:09 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
16/09/21 17:26:09 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(rana); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(rana); groups with modify permissions: Set()
16/09/21 17:26:09 ERROR ExecutorRunner: Error running executor
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find any build directories.
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.CommandBuilderUtils.checkState(CommandBuilderUtils.java:248)
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.AbstractCommandBuilder.getScalaVersion(AbstractCommandBuilder.java:241)
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.AbstractCommandBuilder.buildClassPath(AbstractCommandBuilder.java:195)
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.AbstractCommandBuilder.buildJavaCommand(AbstractCommandBuilder.java:118)
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.WorkerCommandBuilder.buildCommand(WorkerCommandBuilder.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.WorkerCommandBuilder.buildCommand(WorkerCommandBuilder.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.CommandUtils$.buildCommandSeq(CommandUtils.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.CommandUtils$.buildProcessBuilder(CommandUtils.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.ExecutorRunner.org$apache$spark$deploy$worker$ExecutorRunner$$fetchAndRunExecutor(ExecutorRunner.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.ExecutorRunner$$anon$1.run(ExecutorRunner.scala:73)
16/09/21 17:26:09 INFO Worker: Executor app-20160921172608-0000/0 finished with state FAILED message java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find any build directories.
16/09/21 17:26:09 INFO Worker: Asked to launch executor app-20160921172608-0000/1 for Spark shell
16/09/21 17:26:09 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: rana
16/09/21 17:26:09 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: rana
16/09/21 17:26:09 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
16/09/21 17:26:09 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
16/09/21 17:26:09 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(rana); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(rana); groups with modify permissions: Set()
16/09/21 17:26:09 ERROR ExecutorRunner: Error running executor
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find any build directories.
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.CommandBuilderUtils.checkState(CommandBuilderUtils.java:248)
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.AbstractCommandBuilder.getScalaVersion(AbstractCommandBuilder.java:241)
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.AbstractCommandBuilder.buildClassPath(AbstractCommandBuilder.java:195)
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.AbstractCommandBuilder.buildJavaCommand(AbstractCommandBuilder.java:118)
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.WorkerCommandBuilder.buildCommand(WorkerCommandBuilder.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.WorkerCommandBuilder.buildCommand(WorkerCommandBuilder.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.CommandUtils$.buildCommandSeq(CommandUtils.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.CommandUtils$.buildProcessBuilder(CommandUtils.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.ExecutorRunner.org$apache$spark$deploy$worker$ExecutorRunner$$fetchAndRunExecutor(ExecutorRunner.scala:145)
```

Can someone help me to solve this issue??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured out the issue. Actually, I was getting this error because the master was not able to find the launcher for the app (spark-shell).
The master was looking for the directory $SPARK_HOME/launcher/target/scala-2.11, but it didn't find it. As I am running the spark in IntelliJ, so my $SPARK_HOME should have been the project directory where the launcher folder exists. So I changed this and it started working perfectly. Now I can run spark-shell app on this setup.

If you don't want to change your existing setup, then it can also be done by hardcoding the path in the **AbstractCommandBuilder.java** file itself.

Comment: would you be kind enough to explain in more details? changing the $SPARK_HOME does not seem to be the answer as that would break where the spark bin binaries are located